# How do I grant execute permission to an Oracle database user?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, permissions

I'm trying to call a Java function from Oracle database that does the following:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("...");
```

When I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception:
java.security.AccessControlException: the Permission (java.io.FilePermission
<<ALL FILES>> execute) has not been granted to SCOTT. The PL/SQL to grant this
is dbms_java.grant_permission( 'SCOTT', 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', '<<ALL
FILES>>', 'execute' )
```

How do I grant this permission?

---

UPDATE: When I run the following in SQL*Plus (as sysdba):

```
dbms_java.grant_permission( 'SCOTT', 
                            'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', 
                            '<<ALL FILES>>', 
                            'execute' );
```

I get the error:

```
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "/dbms_java..." - rest of line ignored.
SQL> SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "'SYS:java...." - rest of line ignored.
SQL> SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "'<<ALL FIL..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0044: For a list of known commands enter HELP
and to leave enter EXIT.
```

Comment: In order to call a stored procedure, you would either need to type `EXEC` before the stored procedure in SQL*Plus or surround it in a `BEGIN` and `END` block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message actually gives you the exact syntax

```
dbms_java.grant_permission( 'SCOTT', 
                            'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', 
                            '<<ALL FILES>>', 
                            'execute' )
```

It's not obvious to me whether you modified the text of the error message to remove a directory from the error-- normally, the error will tell you a specific directory that you need to grant access to.

If your intention is to allow the Java stored procedure to execute arbitrary shell scripts (this would be very dangerous-- the commands would run as the Oracle operating system user so they would have the ability to bypass any security measures in the database), you should be able to do something like

```
begin
  dbms_java.grant_permission
      ('SCOTT',
       'java.io.FilePermission',
       '<<ALL FILES>>',
       'execute');
  dbms_java.grant_permission
      ('SCOTT',
       'java.lang.RuntimePermission',
       '*',
       'writeFileDescriptor' );
end;
```

Comment: Nope, I didn't modify it at all. I'm assuming it's because there's no exact file, it's running a shell script.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I've updated my question to show the error I'm getting.

Comment: @notfed - I updated my answer with an example.  If you're calling shell scripts, you'll also likely need the `RuntimePermission`.

Comment: Actually I just need to run a specific shell script, so I assume I just change `<<ALL FILES>>` to the pat of this script.  Thanks.

Comment: @notfed - Yes.  If you can lock it down to one script, that would be *much* safer